# Window width changes when 1 element resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a 2 block web page, 1 needs to be resizable using the `resizable()` function of jquery. when one is resized, the second block needs to change its width as well. 
I use the following jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind('resize', function(){

         var left_width = $(".left").width();
         var right_width = $(".middle").width() - left_width;

         $(".right").width(right_width);
   });

   $(".left").resizable();
});
```

the problem is, for some reason `$(window).width()` keeps changing and i cant assign the width to the right block correctly

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3ncnghpv/1/)

the problem [image]

this is what comes up in the console when i log `$(window).width()` ,
sometimes its 1166 , sometime 1183.

Comment: What do you mean by the window width keeps changing? It's not possible to amend the window width through JS. Your fiddle also seems to work fine, without any of the symptoms you describe

Comment: That looks like the scroll bars width, when resizing it seems to show the scroll bar for the fraction of a second that you're working out width.

Comment: @DBS you are right, it was cause of the scroll. thanks. please post is as an answer so i can choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll bar is being displayed for a fraction of a second while resizing, slightly reducing the size of your window.

This seems to sometimes clash with when you calculate the new width of the second area, which reduces the width slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery .css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('resize', function(){

             var left_width = $(".left").width();
             var right_width = $(".middle").width() - left_width;
             console.log(right_width);
            console.log(left_width);
            console.log('window ' + $(".middle").width());
             $(".right").css("width",right_width+"px");
       });

       $(".left").resizable();
    });
```

[EDIT] I misunderstood the problem but the difference is about right scroll of browser

Answer (score 0):

The window size changing is due to the scrollbar appearing on the right of the browser window as `$(window).width()` calculates the size of the viewing area. My recommendation would be to change the `overflow` of the body to `hidden` whilst you are resizing the object. It seems to work on your Fiddle at least.